# Complex proof of fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

can anybody show me how to use Cauchy's Theorem to show that for sufficiently large R, if $\gamma$ is the circle $|z|$=R oriented counter clockwise, then
$\int_\gamma \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz=2\pi i n$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are $p$ and $n$?

Comment: I suggest you pick up any introductory book on complex analysis, free, bought or borrowed, and look at the sections on winding numbers and the residue theorem.

Comment: I just learn about winding number, but not residue. I am not quite sure how to use the winding number part.

Comment: p is n polynomial. And n probably just the degree of polynomial?

Comment: Are you trying to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra with this?

Comment: Not really, the question just say that this is the alternative proof of FTA, but it want me to show $\int_\gamma \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}= 2\pi i n $.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $$p(z) = C\prod_{q=1}^n (z-\rho_q)$$
then $$p'(z) = C\prod_{q=1}^n (z-\rho_q)\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-\rho_q}$$
so that
$$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-\rho_q}.$$
Hence $$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_q} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = 1$$
and $$\int_{|z|=R} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} \;dz = 2\pi i n.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks Marko, the thing is I need to use Cauchy's Theorem instead of FTA.

Comment: The Cauchy Residue Theorem is used on the next to last line.

Comment: I have not learn Residue Theorem. I only learn the winding number part.

Comment: I also have learn the Cauchy integral Theorem.

Comment: Let's see what others have to say. If I have some basic misunderstanding here I will remove my answer.

Comment: And I also have learned Cauchy differentiation formula.

Comment: The Cauchy theorem tells us that $2\pi i\,f(ρ)=\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{z-ρ}dz$. Now use $f(z)=1$ for the terms of the partial fraction decomposition.